# What profit of universal reference usage in range based loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Many times I saw code like this:

```
template<typename Collection>
void Foo(Collection&& c)
{
    for (auto&& i : std::forward<Collection>(c))
    // do something with i
}
```

For all STL containers (except `vector<bool>`) `i` has type of lvalue reference. Is any practical sense to type `auto&&` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the perfect example of where you don't have an lvalue is `std::vector<bool>`. Using `auto&` will not compile, as a prvalue is returned from the iterator.

Also, it happened to me some times to make ranges that did not returned an lvalue from its iterator.

Also, the upside of using `auto&&` is that there is no cases where it won't work. Even of you have a bizarre case where your iterator yield a const rvalue reference, `auto&&` will bind to it.

For teaching, it's also easier to tell "use `auto&&` in your for loops." because it will not cause copy and work everywhere.

There where also a proposal to allow implicit `auto&&` and enable  the syntax `for (x : range)` (I cannot remember which one is it. If you know it, please tell me in the comments)

Comment: *Terse `for` loops*, if memory serves.

Comment: That proposal crashed and burned. I don't see much point in mentioning it.